# iPhone UIControlEvent when touches have ended

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicontrol, touches

I have a volume slider in my application that I'd like to have a sound effect play when the user changes the value. The standard valueChanged event works well here, and I'd like to use it in conjunction with a touches ended signal to trigger the sound at the end. Is there a control event here that I'm missing that would run my method when the touches finish? It doesn't seem like there is a UIControlEventTouchesEnded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to set the slider's `continuous` to NO. Now it emits just one `valueChanged` event, namely when the user is all finished - just what you want to know.

Comment: Bingo! Just what I was looking for. Fortunately the sound effect don't require a constant volume change (like, say, the background music) so this little property will do nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Some code samples would help, but I guess you're looking for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. I'm not sure, if it works with a slider.

Comment: `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` does indeed work with a slider.